# Java program based on searching and sorting

Tags: java

```
public class ZipCodeLocation {

    int zipCode;
    double latitude, longitude; 
    String town, state, county, type;      

    public ZipCodeLocation(int z, double la, double lo, String to, String s, String c, String ty) {        
         zipCode=z;
      latitude=la;
      longitude=lo;
      town=to;
      state=s;
      county=c;
      type=ty;

    }

    public int getZipCode() {
         return zipCode;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
         return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
         return longitude;
    }

    public String getTown() {
         return town;
    }

    public String getState() {
         return state;
    }

    public String getCounty() {
         return county;
    }

    public String getType() {
         return type;
    }

    public String toString() {
         return "";
    }
}

public class Application {

    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {

        Comparable[] zips = new Comparable[42000];
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("zipcodes.txt"));
        //PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter("zipout.txt");

        for( int x=0; x < zips.length; x++) {
             String line = fileScan.next();

             //if
             zips[x] = line;
             //System.out.println(zips[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

there is a text file I am reading from called "zipcodes.txt" and each line in the text file looks like this: "00656","+18.023280","-066.786909","GUAYANILLA","PR","GUAYANILLA","STANDARD"

the next part of this assignment asks to list the towns in rhode island in ascending abc order, but I do not understand how to take just the town out of the array of comparable objects..thank you!

Comment: What have you already tried? Have you read about [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)? Have you thought of maybe making `ZipCodeLocation` implement `Comparable`?

Comment: Your constructor has the equalities backwards.  You set the parameter fields to the class fields.

Comment: I did think of that, but what exactly would that allow me to do? I also considered having the constructor break up the line from the txt file into zipcode, latitude, longitude, town, state, county, type..

Comment: @Nick You don't understand. What Gilbert pointed out is that you are are setting the arguments to the global variables, which are null (or 0). In other words, you need `zipCode=z`, not `z=zipCode`.

Comment: I got what he was saying, I was responding to @MirroredFate about implementing Comparable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a good place to use [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). We can make an anonymous class that can compare based upon whichever property we wish to use.

Assuming that you have correctly created your `ZipCodeLocation` object array (which you are not doing now, but I'll leave that up to you to figure out), you could create a temporary array of the `ZipCodeLocation`s in Rhode Island.

```
ArrayList<ZipCodeLocation> riZips = new ArrayList<ZipCodeLocation>();
//allZips is an array of all your ZipCodeLocations
for(int i = 0; i < allZips.length; i++){
    if(allZips[i].getState() == "RI")
        riZips.add(allZips[i]);
}
```

Then you can just use `Collections.sort` with a `Comparator` to sort it by town name.

```
Collections.sort(riZips, new Comparator<ZipCodeLocation>(){
    public int compare(ZipCodeLocation z1, ZipCodeLocation z2){
        return z1.getTown().compareToIgnoreCase(z2.getTown());
    }
}
```

Easy as pie.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by accumulating each line into a `TreeMap<String,ZipCode>`, where the key is the town name, and the value is the entire `ZipCode` object (containing all values including the town name).

Then you could iterate by its keys ([`Map.keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29)), which would automatically be ordered.

Alternatively, `ZipCode` could implement [`Comparable<ZipCode>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), and then [`Collection.sort(list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) would automatically sort a list of them for you. However, this is only recommended when the sort is only against one key. If it's possible to sort on different keys in different situations, you should go with the map idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with parsing each line. You can use StringTokenizer class, or String.Split() method. Create list of ZipCodeLocation objects from the lines. Iterate through the objects, find the locations where ZipCodeLocation.getTown().equals(anotherZipCodeLocation.getTown()). 
You can save these locations in a list. You can use comparator on the list to sort it, and finally iterate through the sorted list to display the items.